# How to calculate how many points with coordinates (x;y) is in/on/outside of circle

Tags: c++

I have program to write in my C++ course. In coordinate plane we have circle with radius R.Circle center is at the point (xc,yc). Also I have n point with coordinates( for example n=2 and coordinates is (1;1) (-1;-1). I need to calculate how many points there is in a circle, on it and outside of it.. Please help :)

Comment: This sounds like a math problem right now, not a programming one.

Comment: What I understand is you have a collection of values (points), and you want to count how many of them match a predicate (is the point within a circle). Is that correct? See [std::count_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

Comment: Sounds like you could get a bunch of examples by searching the internet for "c++ points outside circle".

Comment: Represent your points as complex numbers.  See the std::abs() function [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/abs)

Comment: Find the magnitude between a given point and the centre of the circle, if the result is < the radius then the point is in the circle. If it needs to be performant then square the radius and check against the magSqr between the centre of the circle and a given point.

Comment: C++ provides `hypot()`, so if you subtract `cx` from `x` and `cy` from `y`...

Comment: @MFisherDX ? Absolute numbers are not complex and why would making the coordinates abs help?

Comment: @DreamsOfElectricSheep Complex numbers have a real and an imaginary part.  2D points have an X and Y component.  So you can treat a 2D point as a complex number -- and there is great support in C++ for std::complex.  To find the distance between two points p1 and p0, represent p1 and p0 as std::complex<double> and call std::abs(p0-p1).  I use std::complex almost all the time I need 2D geometry in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate distance between circle center and the point. The formula of distance between two points is:

```
d = sqrt( (xc - x)^2 + (yc - y)^2 )
```

where: (xc, yc) - coordinates of circle center, (x, y) - coordinates of your point.

if the distance is greater then radius then point is outside the circle (d > R)

Then you need repeat this for n points and remember how many of them are inside and how many are outside. and that's all.

Now you have an algorithm you can try to code it!

Answer (score 0):

Equation of a circle: `R^2 = (xc - x)^2 + (yc-y)^2` where `(xc, yc)` are coordinates of circle center. `(x, y)` - coordinates of point, R - radius. So:

```
double distance = sqrt((xc - x)*(xc - x) + (yc-y)*(yc-y));
if (distance < R)
{
    // inside
}
else if(distance > R)
{
    // outside
}
else
{
    // on circle 
}
```

Comment: I feel dumb now to not understand.. Thank you :) This page is way better than my teacher

Comment: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/02/whats-so-hard-about-finding-a-hypotenuse/

Answer (score 0):

Simple math...

Surface of a square is calculated by `S = pi*r^2`
given r in pixels, S would come in pixels...

it is worthy to note, that this method is approximation, because it is not over a discrete plane

In order to be more precise (though, considerably slower):
refer to @Sandro answer, and check the distance to each point on your plane..
with two optimizations that you may want to consider:

1. exclude the outer Bounding box
   You need to check only the pixels `x in [xc - r, xc + r] U y in [yc - r, yc + r]`
2. automatically include inscribed square
   You can include every pixel in `x in (xc - sqrt(2)r, xc + sqrt(2)r) U (yc - sqrt(2)r, yc + sqrt(2)r)`

references:

[Circles Inscribed in Squares](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/circles-inscribed-in-squares)

[Squares Circumscribed by Circles](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/squares-circumscribed-by-circles)